# Choosing between two models based on cross validation error

Tags: r, cross-validation, simulation

I am seeking to compare the cross validation error for two models using R, maybe more in the future. Using the `cv.glm` function from the `boot` package produces a number that varies each time. Since it varies I ran it 100 times for each model and plotted the results using this code:

```
library(boot)
sink.model    <- glm(mpg~.,          data=mtcars)
simpler.model <- glm(mpg~am+wt+qsec, data=mtcars)

sinkcv <- numeric(100)
simpcv <- numeric(length(sinkcv))
system.time(
  for (i in 1:length(simpcv)){
    sinkcv[i] <- cv.glm(mtcars, sink.model,    K=5)$delta[2]
    simpcv[i] <- cv.glm(mtcars, simpler.model, K=5)$delta[2]
  }
)
library(lattice)
densityplot(~sinkcv+simpcv, auto.key=TRUE)
```

This took about 15 seconds to create 100 estimated cross-validated error values for each model. If we overlay them in the same density plot we see that the simpler model has much less variation and an overall smaller mean. Therefore I would choose the simpler model for prediction because it has a lower error rate on average, as well as lower variation. Is there some fundamental flaw in that approach? If so could you maybe point me in the direction of some resource that might explain why?

Edit for clarification: I am trying to justify the usage of one model for prediction versus another. I am calculating CV error for each model and then plotting them. I see that each time I do this one distribution has less variance and a lower mean value than the other distribution. I would like to say the model that produces a lower CV error mean with less variance would be the better model to choose for prediction but I would like to know if there is something else that should be considered before coming to that conclusion.

Second edit: I am not interested so much in why a simpler model predicts better but whether it is a sound approach to perform several CVs on two different models and then compare those results to each other with the intent of choosing the one with the lower error rates?

[image: CV error for two different models]

Comment: I don't follow what your question is here. Are you just wondering why one model is less variable? Can you provide more information? Be aware that code check is off topic here.

Comment: When I plot the errors for one model I see a much tighter distribution as well as a much lower mean in comparison to the errors produced by the other model. Is this a sound method for justifying the usage of one model versus another?

Comment: Could you post the plot that troubles you?

Comment: Yes, I have posted the plot. I see that the CV error for one model varies much less than the other and has a lower mean. Does this on its own imply that one model is better for prediction than the other? Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

CV is an empirical method to estimate prediction error.  If you search the net you will see that LOO CV is asymptotic to AIC and when K>1, CV is asymptotic to BIC*.  In any event, in the absence of having divided the data into a training set and a testing set, CV is probably the best method to estimate predictive accuracy.
Nor is it necessarily surprising that the simpler model predicts better.  If there are variables that are highly correlated with each other or if there are variables with low or no correlation with the dependent variable, the more complicated model should have greater variance in it's predictive accuracy and likely higher bias.

- In fact you will find explanations of this on previous stackexchange threads.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and I did try to find more info about this but the answers I found seemed specific to one scenario. I am looking for something more general I suppose. I was expecting the simpler model to have better predictive accuracy, I am not surprised. 

What I am trying to ascertain is whether or not there is a fundamental flaw in performing a large amount of CVs for each model and then comparing the results? I tried to make the construction of models simplistic so that the result would be that the two had largely different measured error values.

Comment: Well certainly repeated CV is better than a single usage.  If you use the caret package, repeated CV is one of the options.  If you are asking is there a result/theorem saying that asymptotically ( as the number of CV attempts goes to infinity) CV converges to the true variance and bias, I don't know of such off hand.  There is a book by Abu-Mustafah and another by Mohri on the mathematical foundations of ML.  It's possible that they will have such a result.

Comment: I googled asymptotic convergence of cross validation and there are a number of papers.  This https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~laan/Research/Research_subpages/Papers/likcrossvalf.pdf  may answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not understand what you meant by asymptotically at first. Now that I do I will proceed to check those out. Thanks!